# Using async/await and callback functions together inside the rest api service in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am trying this code that has an await function to get the user information.
Then with info we try to pay.
But in my code It is not waiting for pay result.

```js
const iyziPayPromised = async (request) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        iyzipay.checkoutFormInitialize.create(request, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err)
            }
            return resolve(result.checkoutFormContent + '<div id="iyzipay-checkout-form" class="responsive"></div>')
        })
    })
}


router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    const user_info = await findOne({user_id: 1})
    const price = 10
    const request = {user_info}
    const result = await iyziPayPromised(request)
    res.send(result)
})
```

since `iyzipay.checkoutFormInitialize.create()` accepts callback only, I tried to change to promise and then wait for it to give response. But still not waiting for it.

Comment: btw `iyziPayPromised = async (` the async here is unnecessary as you're already returning a promise.

Comment: is it erroring and your not catching it?

Comment: its not erroring but not waiting for the result

Comment: @Angels What else does it do then? What is the `result` you get?

Comment: `But still not waiting for it.` how do you confirm that?

Comment: I get 'undefined <div id="iyzipay-checkout-form" class="responsive"></div>'

Comment: @Angels we still don't know what `result` is. Please share that

Answer (score 0):

BTW err with callback is not triggering in iyzipay system

Instead they give `"status":"success"` or `"status":"failure"` in the result

Instead of doing this maybe you should put `res.send` into the callback function.

I would prepare the system in this way

```
const iyziPayCheckout = (request,callback) => {
        iyzipay.checkoutFormInitialize.create(request, callback)
}


router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    const user_info = await findOne({user_id: 1})
    const price = 10
    const request = {user_info}
    const result = iyziPayCheckout(request, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            }else{
                if(result.status === "success"){
                   res.send(result.checkoutFormContent + '<div id="iyzipay-checkout-form" class="responsive"></div>')
                }else{
                   res.send(result)
                }
           }
        })
    }))
    res.send(result)
})
```